# Como fazer uma sidebar passar por cima do conteúdo do site sem ficar empurrando?

Tags: html5, sidebar

```css
*{
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    width: 99%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f0fcfc;
    
}
#Barra1{
    width: 101%; 
    height: 10%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    background-color: #305c8c;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#TextoBarra1{
    
    color: white;
}




#Barra2{
    width: 101%; 
    height: 30px;
    
    vertical-align:middle; 
    background-color: #193b6a;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#BTBarra1{
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #193b6a;
    border: 0 solid #193b6a;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: BloggerSans-Bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.BTBarra{
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #193b6a;
    border: 0 solid #193b6a;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: BloggerSans-Bold;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.BTBarra:hover{
    color: #193b6a;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0 solid #193b6a;
}

nav.menu-lateral{
    width: 80px;
    height: 88vh;
    background-color: #2596be;
    padding: 40px 0 40px 1%;
    box-shadow: 3px 0 0 #193b6a;
    float:left;
    left: 0;
    transition: .4s;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
nav.menu-lateral:hover{
    width: 300px;
    transition: .4s;
}



ul{
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}


ul li.item-menu{
    transition:.2s;
}
ul li.item-menu:hover{
    background-color: #193b6a;
}
ul li.item-menu a{
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding:20px 4%;
    font-family: 'BloggerSans-Bold';
    display: flex;
    line-height: 40px;
}
ul li.item-menu a .txt-link{
    margin-left:40px;
}
ul li.item-menu a .Icon > i{
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


.quadrado-inicial{
    background-color: #193b6a;
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#Organização{
    color:white; 
    margin-top:7%;
    
    
}

#btinicial {
    display: block;
    background-color: #00a1ff;
    border: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 11em;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#btinicial:active {
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.2rem #dfd9d9;
    transform: translateY(0.2rem);
}

#btinicial:hover:not(:disabled) {
    background: #0080ca;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0.1rem #bcb4b4;
}

#btinicial:disabled {
    cursor: auto;
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Início</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'FonteInfo';
            src: url('Cuckoo Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'BloggerSans-Bold';
            src: url('BloggerSans-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
            font-weight:lighter;
            font-style:normal;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Barra1">
        <img src="img/InfoImg.PNG" style="height: 50px;"><p style="font-family:FonteInfo;" id="TextoBarra1">Informática</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Barra2">
        <a href="inicio.html" class="BTBarra">Início</a>
        <a href="Contato.html" class="BTBarra">Contato</a>
        <a href="Sobre.html" class="BTBarra">Sobre</a>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <nav class="menu-lateral">
            <ul>
                <li class="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="Icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-brush"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="txt-link">
                            Design Gráfico
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="Icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-pc-display"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="txt-link">
                            Informática Básica
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="Icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-tools"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="txt-link">
                            Arquitetura
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="item-menu">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="Icon">
                            <i class="bi bi-database-fill-gear"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="txt-link">
                            Banco de Dados
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    </span>

        <center>
            <nav id="Organização">

                <button type="button" id="btinicial" style="float: left; width:9em; margin-left:8%;display:block;">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>
                            <img src="img/RelógioImg.png" style="width: 150px; margin-top:10px;">
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <h3>Momentos Marcantes</h3>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </button>

                <button type="button" id="btinicial" style="float: right; width:9em; padding: 3rem; 
                margin-right:11%;">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>
                            <img src="img/SobreImgQuad.jpg" style="width: 200px; margin-top:10px;">
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <h3>Sobre</h3>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </button>

                <button type="button" id="btinicial" style="float: right; width:9em; padding: 2rem;margin-right:6%;">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span>
                            <img src="img/ProfsImg.jpg" style="width: 150px; margin-top:10px; ">
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <h3>Professores</h3>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </button>
            </nav>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Adicione a propriedade fixed no css #Barra1 ou na div desejada

```
#Barra1{
width: 101%; 
height: 10%;
margin-top: -10px;
vertical-align:middle; 
background-color: #305c8c;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Experimente colocar esse código na SideBar:

```
position: absolute;
z-index: 99;
```

Eu testei com a SideBar:

```
nav.menu-lateral {
width: 80px;
height: 88vh;
background-color: #2596be;
padding: 40px 0 40px 1%;
box-shadow: 3px 0 0 #193b6a;
float: left;
left: 0;
transition: .4s;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
position: absolute;
z-index: 99; }
```

Como ficou:

[Exemplo de como ficou o código fornecido](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGBFY.png)